# Import a javaScript file in vuejs2 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a beginner with the Vuejs framework and I'm having a problem in using js libraries in my Vue project... I'll be so grateful if anyone could help me

btw I tried adding this in my main.js file and it didn't work

import template from './assets/js/template.js'
Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$template', { value: template })

template.js is my js file

Comment: would you please show how `template.js` looks like?

Comment: The import method is correct. So something wrong in js file .

Comment: template.js contains the following code:
jquery(document).ready(function($) {

 $(".headroom").headroom({
  "tolerance": 20,
  "offset": 50,
  "classes": {
   "initial": "animated",
   "pinned": "slideDown",
   "unpinned": "slideUp"
  }
 });

});

Comment: Please do not add code scripts in comment area. Instead modify the question with the script

Answer (score 0):

in order to use third party libraries or other scripts just add the script tag with the source pointing to the location of the .js to the index.html file.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work :/ I thought there were other solutions.. 
Thank youuu anyway